# How to simulate non existing method error in __call?

Tags: php

Maybe strange question, but...
I have a magic __call method, that return instances of certain classes, or, if there are no such class, calls same method in underlying object.

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    $class = 'My\\Namespace\\' . $name;

    if (class_exists($class, true)) {

        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($class);
        return $reflect->newInstanceArgs($arguments);

    } elseif (is_callable([$this->connector, $name])) {

        return call_user_func_array([&$this->connector, $name], $arguments);
    } else {
        // ????
    }
}
```

But what to do in else block? Can I simulate undefined method error? Or what exception to throw would be correct?

Comment: Would be very helpful to have a "fallback" to default behavior. Something like:
    
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        if (! in_array($name, $this->allowedVirtualMethods)) {
            return DO_DEFAULT_STUFF_WHEN_METHOD_NOT_AVAILABLE;
        }
    
        // do something
    }

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can trigger PHP errors manually using `trigger_error`:

```
trigger_error('Call to undefined method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$name.'()', E_USER_ERROR);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php

Comment: This would show a usefull errormessage, but `is_callable($myclass, 'forbitten_method')` still would return true for the forbitten method